# How to facet filter search with a colon in the value?

Tags: algolia

I'm not entirely sure what *faceting* means, but it looks like a way to scope a query to a subset of records with key-value match. I want to facet filter on social accounts like `account = facebook:123` or `account = twitter:567`.

> Filter the query by a list of facets. Facets are separated by commas and each facet is encoded as `attributeName:value`.
>   -- [algolia docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#faceting-parameters)

The issue is the syntax includes a colon already. I haven't had any luck with either two colons `account:facebook:123` or uri encoded `account:facebook%3A123`.

Is there a way to facet query without changing the data?

Is this the best way scope queries to a subset of documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct about the scoping capabilities of the facets. You can also think of faceting as filtering.

There is no issue with passing colons inside your facet filter, but as soon as you start wondering what syntax to use, just use this syntax:

```
{ facetFilters: '["facetKey:facetValue"]' }
```

The JS client should encode it on its own.

Here, my guess it that your didn't declare the attribute `account` in your `attributesForFaceting`. You can either do this using the API or in your Algolia dashboard, in the Display tab of your index.